# Copying transaction table data of from production environment to development in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, toad

I want to copy the transaction table data from production environment to development environment in Oracle 11i.

Currently, we are manually copying the data from production environment to development environment using "copy data to another schema" option in Toad. But, I want this to be done by programmatically or some options where in I need to specify the list of tables names to be copied, source environment and destination environment. Once I specified all the required details, it has to copy the data from production environment to development environment.If I do this I can avoid manual mistakes.

Please suggest the various option to accomplish the above task.

**Note:** I'm a beginner in Oracle as well as in Toad.

Comment: use datapump to export & import the data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Export` then `Import`.

**Table Exports/Imports**

The TABLES parameter is used to specify the tables that are to be exported. The following is an example of the table export and import syntax.

```
expdp scott/tiger@db11g tables=TRANSACTION directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=TRANSACTION.dmp logfile=expdpTRANSACTION.log

impdp scott/tiger@db11g tables=TRANSACTION directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=TRANSACTION.dmp logfile=impdpTRANSACTION.log
```

Make sure your `TEST_DIR` exists, and is accessible.

Here you go with the docs.

[Import](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/dp_import.htm#SUTIL900)

[Export](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/dp_export.htm#SUTIL200)

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks Team for all your response,

I have created link to test db from development db and then selected the test db records from dev db and inserted into development db. Please share me is this approach is correct or share the scenario where this approach will fail.

In development db, I created a link to test db. 

“CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK TestDBLink
CONNECT TO userid IDENTIFIED BY pwd
USING servicename;”

Script to copy data from test to development environment,

TRUNCATE TABLE Table1;
TRUNCATE TABLE Table2;
TRUNCATE TABLE Table3;

INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT * FROM Table1@TestDBLink;

INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT * FROM Table2@TestDBLink;

INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT * FROM Table3@TestDBLink;

Thanks,
Prakash.
```